# Mattapalli Lakshmi Narasimha

Tags: puranas, narasimha

Mattapalli is a place in Vijayawada in Andhra. There is a Lakshmi Narasimha temple in which the God is with his consort Rajyalakshmi. The krishnaveni river is so sacred. Gods Krishna, Shiva and King of birds Garuda visited this shrine and stood in a line to worship Lakshmi Narasimha. In Narasimha purana or any other puranas the greatness of the God is described? There is a ashtagam composed by Mukkur Lakshmi Narasimhachariyar known as mattapalli mangalashtagam.

Answer (score 1):

> Mattapalli Mangalashtakam in English:-
>
> Mattapallinivasaya madhuranandarupine 
>   mahayajnasvarupaya srinirusimhaya mangalam

Glories to the sweet, blissful Lord of Mattapalli, Sri Lakshmi Narasimha, who is described in the Vedic Yagnas as the One who is attainable by the Madhu Vidya form of Bhakti Yoga.

> krisnavenitatathaya sarvabhistapradayine
>   prahladapriyarupaya srinisimhaya mangalam

Glories to the Lord, who resides on the bank of the river Krishna, the bestower of all auspiciousness, One who is dear to those who are as devoted as prahlada.

> garrtasthitayadhiraya gambhiraya mahatmane
>   sarvarista vinasaya srinrsimhaya mangalam

Glories to the brave majestic Lord, the dispeller of all obstacles, who resides in a mountain cave.

> rigyajussamarupaya mantrarudhayahimate
>   sritanam kalpavkrsaya srinrsimhaya mangalam

Glories to the Lord who is seen in the four Vedas, who is seen in the mantras, 
who showers the desired to those who surrender to Him.

> guhasaraya guhyaya guhyavidyasvarupine
>   kuharante viharaya srinrsimhaya mangalam

Glories to the Lord, who can be experienced through esoteric Guhya Vidhya.

> sripalayadrimadhasthaya nidhaya madhuraya ca
>   sukrapradaya devaya srinrsimhaya mangalam

Glories to Him, who confers happiness, who is the beautiful treasure of Mattapalli in between the two kshetras of Vadapalli and Vadadri.

> tapaniyaaarahasaya tapaaatraya vinasine
>   natanam parijataya srinrsimhaya mangalam

Glories to the secret described by the Tapaniya Upanishad;
the Lord destroys the Tapa Trayas(3 form of troubles) of his devotees.

> rajyalakshsmya sametaya ragadvesa vinasine
>   mattapalli nivasaya srinrsimhaya mangalam

Glories to the Lion of Mattapalli who is ever with Raajyalakshmi 
and removes the feelings of greed and hatred from his devotees.

> mukkur nrsimhadasena proktam mangalashtakam
>   yah pathet sraddaya bhaktya sarvapapaih pramucayate

He who recites with sincere devotion, the sacred Mangalam verses,
composed by the Lord and recited through Mukku Narasimha Dasan gets all his ins destroyed.

Mattapalli Mangalashtakam MP3
http://www.prapatti.com/slokas/mp3/mattapallimangalaashtakam.mp3

You tube links--

1.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UwcPj1FzEo
2.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtyTKHS5jdg
3.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHw01yEn92I